# Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_shortcode_param()

Tags: php, wordpress

I updated the WP Bakery Visual Composer and my site is down. This is the error I get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_shortcode_param() in
>   /usr/www/users/capecoz/wp-content/themes/jkreativ-themes/admin/vc/extend.php
>   on line 27

Comment: may be this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-add_shortcode_param/ work for you

Comment: I had this issue on a client, i see that the **add_shortcode_param()** function was **deprecated** by WP Bakery since version 4.4 My client uses a theme that was made before 4.4 version, to fix it i simply followed the instruction of WP Bakery and **put a VC_ in front of the call** of the function where the *"undefined function error"* occurs, like this: **vc_add_shortcode_param()**

Answer (score 0):

Add_`shortcode_param()`.

This function was called, but it's not defined, so you will need to define this function in your theme's `function.php` file.